# After the Merge with proof-of-stake, how a lightclient verify the block header?

Tags: light-clients, validators, block-header, the-merge

In my understanding, date back to proof-of-work, the block header is self-verifiable because of the difficulty, nonce and block hash value. But after the Merge, the block is attested by several validators. To verify a block header, the lightclient should first know the validator set and the proposer of the corresponding block, which are randomly chosen by RANDAO. How is this possible to trace the valid validator set under the current implementation or there are some other magic way to do workarounds?

p.s. I know that in Cosmos lightclient, all validator changes are directly included in the block header, so the lightclient can trace the validator set. But I haven't seen the similar design in Ethereum.